# How can I store and return data from an HTTP response?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the request module to make a request to an API which sends me a Base64 encoded response which is a file.

```
    app.get("/report", async(request, response) => {
    const newRequest = new mdl.Request
    const newDatasources = new  mdl.Datasources
    const newVariables = new mdl.VariablesType
    const VariablesArray = []
    const myArray = []

    newRequest.Uri = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/listing.docx"
 newRequest.Async = false
    newRequest.OutputFormat = "html"
    newVariables.Name = "Var1"
    newVariables.Type = "text"
    newVariables.Value = "Hello World!"
    VariablesArray.push(newVariables)
    newDatasources.Name = "JSON"
    newDatasources.Type = "JSON"
    newDatasources.Data = "ewogICAgImxpc3RQcmljZSI6ICIkODc5LDAwMCIsCiAAgICAgInB1cmNoQ29udHJhY3REYXRlIjogIiIsCiAgICAgICAgImVuZGluZ0RhdGUiOiAiIgogICAgfQp9"
    newDatasources.Variables = VariablesArray
    myArray.push(newDatasources)

    newRequest.Datasources = myArray

    const req_data = JSON.stringify(newRequest)

    const options = {
        hostname: 'report.sample.com',
        port: 80,
        path: '/v1/reports',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': req_data.length
        }
      }
      const req = http.request(options, (error, resp, body) => {
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

        resp.on('data', (d) => {
          process.stdout.write(d)
        })
      })

      resp.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error(error)
      })

      req.write(req_data)

      req.end()

      response.send("done")
    });
```

This prints out the received data on my terminal, but how can I go about storing it in a variable and return it as a response to a request? just some background to what i am doing. I am building a report request which is then send to a api via the request which returns me the data in form of the encoded string

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell exactly what you're using to run this.

Use

```
res.status(200).send({success: true, data: data})
```

if you're using express.

Comment: I update the code to include the whole route. Data does not is not accessible

Comment: You don't have to include the data variable, it was just my attempt at an example. If this code sends the response, that's all that matters. The response is the object that is passed into .send()

Comment: Sorry that's not the issue. http request return the response as a stream so i have to put the returned data into a variable to be able to return it.